# How to stop remote connection/intrusion?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, security, remote-control

A person within my network got access to my MacBook Pro through Wi-fi, and somehow now he can connect remotely. I cannot change the Wi-fi password because we both pay for it.  So, my only choice so far is to avoid not to use Wi-Fi at all, until I learn on what to do to remove his fingers of my machine.

I did 3 factory reset, cleaned up all my files but as soon I am within his range he is again messing with my files. I tripled check all my security settings such as firewall, disabled infrared receiver, created a vault, even I now use a firmware password to log into my machine.

How to stop his remote connection?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! I've edited your question to focus on the facts but we may need more details to help you here. How exactly does he mess with your computer? Does he have an account on your Mac? Do you use an easy-to-guess (or already known) password? Do you have any Sharing option enabled in Settings?

Comment: There are so many things that could have been setup that it is really hard to say. Some basic things to start with: disable the following in System Preferences>Sharing: File Sharing, Screen Sharing, Remote Management, Remote Login. Look on your computer for things like LogMeIn or TeamViewer. If you find them, remove them properly (might help to visit their website for proper instructions). Last resort: change the WiFi password. If this jerk can't stop messing with your stuff, this gives you leverage to make him fix it. Or call the police. What he is doing is a felony most likely.

Comment: Is it possible you have the Computer to Computer Network Enabled ?

Comment: What is a factory reset and which files exactly did you clean? It's entirely possible you are restoring the settings that are compromising the machine, but it's hard to know without you documenting a bit more what "access" means precisely and whether you are restoring compromised settings and apps after each "reset".

Answer (score 4):

Disable (uncheck) in System Preferences+Sharing: 
File Sharing, 
Screen Sharing, 
Remote Management, 
Remote Login + (check in allow access for ?) who has the permission.

also check if there is a user profile set up that is not yours.

Comment: First of all,thanks for editing my question.  I was writing a "journal" of what I was "able" to find, but it looks like I can't write long comments.  Therefore, my questions will imply what I (think) is happening:

Comment: When setting up the network, on my mac, WINS is loading it up with an old bios name, that was created when my partition drive disappear.  So, I cannot change the bios name since it is grey-out. It loads automatically   :(

Comment: How to disable TCIP/IP over NETbioS?

Comment: How can I stop LMHOST, "NIC in the Sharing server", stop VPN-PPTP, and how do (again) fix the bios?  Thank you so very much!!!!

Comment: Yes, it seems that there is another profile on my machine. To make matters worse, I believe it has higher privileges than I have or it just seems that way.  I did look into the Network account server.. "Directory Utility", then Active Directory.. It was modified ;(.  How do fix that? user groups and there are so many "groups" and users.. I simply got so frustrated and confused :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you get a littlesnitch. littlesnitch will track your Web traffic and tell you which applications are sending data from your computer. Be sure to run it awhile because it will trigger a number of alerts. In trail mode, it will run for three hours per boot for a about a month.
http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

Comment: I will follow your recommendatin on littlesnitch.